# How to stack html elements with same class on top of each other in Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like to stack every element with class `.box` above each other but positioned `20px` offset (`top` and `left`) from each other. How do I do that with Sass?

I want that every subsequent `.box` is offset by `20px` from its precedent `.box` and have their `z-index` incremented by 2.

I've tried this Sass:

```
$selector: box;
$counter: 5;

@for $i from 1 through $counter {
  .#{$selector} {
    top: ($counter * 10) + $i;
    left: ($counter * 10) + $i;
    z-index: $counter + $i;
  }
}

.box {
  font-family: "Oswald Light";
  color: $darkenedGrey;
  width: 750px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid $lightenedGrey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: $white;

  p {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
}
```

HTML (dynamically generated via Backbone. There're about 5 of these `.box`):

```
<article class="box">
  <h2 class="name"><%= name %></h2>
  <h3 class="from">From: <%= from %></h3>
  <p><%= tel %> | <a href="mailto:<%= email %>"><%= email %></a></p>
  <p>Role: <span class="role"><%= info %></span></p>
  <p>On: <%= date %></p>
  <a class="delete-btn" href="#">delete</a> | <a class="view-details-btn" href="#user/<%= id %>">view details</a>
</article>
```

Also, here `$counter` says `5`, but there could be more than 5 `.box`, because they're created dynamically, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please provide the markup as well.

Comment: Hi @cimmanon, thanks for your response. I've updated the question. The markup is a template in Backbone, so it's generated dynamically. At the moment there are about 5 `article.box` generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You math is all funky. Be sure to place `.box` inside a placed element using `position: relative` for this to work:

```
$zCounter: 2;
$pCounter: 20;
@for $i from 1 through $counter {
  .#{$selector} {
    top: $pCounter * $i;
    left: $pCounter * $i;
    z-index: $zCounter * $i;
  }
}
```

I am somewhat familiar with sass so my syntax could be rusty.

Comment: Thanks @beautifulcoder, the code doesn't work yet. I think it's something to do with `:nth-child()`. I've tried `.#{$selector}:nth-child(#{$i})` inside your code but it's still not working. When I check firebug I get `.box:nth-child(6) {z-index: 12;}` only, instead of several `.box:nth-child(1), .box:nth-child(2), ... etc`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was effectively with `:nth-child` not being added to the selector and omitting `px` or any unit to the values of `top` and `left`.

I got it to work with (notice the `nth-child` and `px`:

```
$selector: agent;
$counter: 7;
$zCounter: 2;

@for $i from 1 through $counter {
  .#{$selector}:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    top: #{15 * $i}px;
    left: #{15 * $i}px;
    z-index: $zCounter + $i;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. `nth-child` makes sense since it will overwrite everything by default. I totally forgot about `px` units. Definitely good stuff to know.